# UIButton changes image back to original on focus (tvOS)

Tags: swift, uibutton, focus, tvos

I have a button that acts as a switch: I check the current state of the variable (stored in used defaults) and attribute it in `viewDidAppear`

When I press the left button (ignore the right one) it is acts as it should - swapping out 2 `UIImage`s on button's `UIImageView`

[image]

but as soon as button goes out of focus - button switches image back to the default one. if no default image is specified in IB - button just goes to blank image.

How can I ensure button keeps the image after is goes out of focus? Do I need to implement additional focus delegate methods or something? I'm new tvOS and some things just don't make sense to me yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doh, it appears you cannot just swap out `UIImage` on `UIImageView` property and have to use a button setter for such matter:

`button.setImage(UIImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)`

It works fine this way